# Edit xml in program files throgh code

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I have a xml file in  `C:\Program files(86)\Application` .
I can edit the file only through note pad which is open as Administrator. I want to edit the file through code. Is it possible to edit the xml file through code?
I am using windows 8.1 and visual studio 12.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But your program should be started as Administrator too.

Comment: See following posting : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568354/how-to-edit-or-update-srgs-grammar-using-c-sharp/30570568#30570568

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `Application Manifest File` to your project and replace

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

with

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

This way your application will require administrator rights to run.